# Excel SEARCH function always returns #N/B

Tags: excel, excel-formula

In Excel I have a lists of **FQDN**'s. I am trying to get the hostname out of the **FQDN** (everything before first occurrence of a dot (.) ).

I have Googled a bit and found that I need the **LEFT** function and combine it with the **`SEARCH()`** function. When I tried it, I got a #N/B result back from the formula.

After some troubleshooting, I noticed that the SEARCH function is the cause of the errors. I tried something like this (`LEFT()` = `LINKS()` & `SEARCH()` = `ZOEKEN()` (Dutch)):

```
=LINKS(A1;ZOEKEN(".";A1) -1 )
```

Where A1 contains something like myhostname.mydomain.nl. But even when I try something like this, I get the `#N/B` results:

```
=ZOEKEN(".";"test.atest")
```

I don't know why I get a error as a result. I believe the syntax is correct. If I'm correct I have to get a index from the `SEARCH()` function? How do I get the expected results?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Works fine:

[image]

```
LEFT(A3,FIND(".",A3,1)-1)
```

I used find() instead of search, but is the "." you search for the same as the "." in the text? may be a character set issue.

Search() also works:

```
LEFT(A3,SEARCH(".",A3,1)-1)
```

Comment: Thank you, using FIND instead of SEARCH the same function now works.

Answer (score 1):

With the stupid translations that Dutch excel brings: try giving a cell in VBA the formula in English (that you know works) and then check what the formula is in Excel since it auto-translates it. Something like:

```
Sub test()
    Range("C3").Formula2 = "=LEFT(A3,SEARCH(""."",A3,1)-1)"
End Sub
```

Which gives:

[image]

As you can see, `SEARCH()` in Dutch excel gives: `VIND.SPEC()`

As for the `ZOEKEN()` function, that's more to check if it exists in a 1D-range (the full value), for what I can tell.